# python serial.Serial() module not found error

Tags: pi-3, python, serial

I am trying to connect to the serial ports a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B running Raspbian through Python.

`import serial` works fine but `ser = serial.Serial("dev/ttyAMA0", baudrate=9600)` yields this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Serial'
```

Comment: Have you created a file called `serial.py` at any point and put it in an import location (e.g. your current directory)? That would likely break things. Also, how did you install pySerial?

Comment: No. I there is no file named `serial.py` at any point and I have deleted every .pyc file and used `from serial import serial` as I am importing the module not the class still getting the error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First uninstall serial with `sudo pip uninstall serial` (thank you so much Ali!)

Then, if `import serial` does not work anymore: use `sudo pip install pyserial`. This will install the correct serial module for the RP.

Comment: BaxMode's answer helped me. (but I cannot up vote it yet due to lack of reputation here) I pip installed serial, when I should have installed pyserial.
(I'm using Windows with Anaconda, so `conda install pyserial` worked for me.)

Comment: This worked for me.

Comment: This works, but I'll add a bit more explanation.  There are two different packages that provide a module called 'serial' to the python system.  One is called 'serial' by pip, and that is a serialization library (nothing to do with serial ports).  The other is called 'pyserial' by pip, and that is the one that does serial port handling on the system.  It is a very unfortunate name conflict in the python ecosystem, that I've hit myself.  Uninstalling the serialization module and making sure the serial port handling module is installed should work.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and I tried all the suggestions I encountered on the internet, but non has worked for me. Finally, I was able to solve the problem by uninstalling the `serial` package from `usr/local/lib` that had the issue for some reason. you can uninstall this package by `sudo pip uninstall serial`.
Here is what you can try:

- write this short piece of code
  `import serial
  print(serial.__file__),`.
  This outputs the path of the module being imported in your code.
- if the output is `/usr/local/lib/pythonx.x/dist-packages/serial/__init__.py`, then go ahead and uninstall `serial`. If it was `/usr/lib/pythonx.x/dist-packages/serial/__init__.py`, then you have another type of problem.
- repeat the 1st step after the uninstall and check that the output is the second one
- now try your code again

PS: you may need to use `pip3` instead of `pip` in case you are using python3.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

have a look at [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11403932/python-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-serial).
I have the same issue because I have installed serial instead of pyserial.
To check, enter
dir(serial)
If you do not see the Serial method, you have the wrong package

Answer (score -1):

Yes this topic is one year old but i wanted to share the solution that worked for me for those who might need it anyway

As Ali said, try to locate your program using the following from terminal :

```
 sudo python3
 import serial
```

`print(serial.__file__)` **--> Copy**

`CTRL+D #(to get out of python)`

`sudo python3`**-->paste**`/__init__.py`

Activating `__init__.py` will say to your program "ok i'm going to use Serial from python3". My problem was that my python3 program was using Serial from python 2.7

Other solution: remove other python versions

Cao

Sources :
Tryhard